# Custom Primefaces Renderer in an external jar: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.4. In order to have a scrollable header on the TabView widget, I implemented a custom renderer, and some custom js. This works fine for me, except the renderer must be in the main web-project.

We are using a separate project containing new components and new composites. The new renderer of course should also be placed in that project. But then the Webapp classloader does not find the renderer and I get a

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.comp.component.tabview.WSTabViewRenderer
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
```

Comment: The JAR is placed in `/WEB-INF/lib`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it by reading about another problem.

The project containing the renderer had an wrong structure. The faces-config.xml file needs to be placed in the META-INF directory. But I had the META-INF directory in an wrong subfolder. Correct would have been placing it under "src/main/java/META-INF" (we are using maven3).